# Opening application from current application

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Android app that can open another app I have using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
intent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("myOtherAppPackageName");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(intent);
```

Which works perfectly, the only thing is the app force closes when I don't have the other app installed, which  makes perfect sense. My question is how do I get my app to open the Play Store to the specific app for someone to download if they do not already have the other app? I would assume do the exact same thing except I don't have the package name for the Play Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have the package name you can just do this

```
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                    "market://details?id=" + "packagename"));
                startActivity(marketIntent);
```

that will launch the play store on the page for that application

Comment: Great thanks! Now let me ask another quick question. Since I won't know if they have it or not what exception do I need to throw in order to redirect them to the market if they don't already have it?

Comment: I believe it is `ActivityNotFoundException` but it also could be `NameNotFoundException`. to make sure i would just uninstall the app and let it crash just so you know for sure. You also could do a check beforehand using `PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("packagename",PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);` in a try/catch where you catch `NameNotFoundException`

Answer (score 0):

If you know package lets use this example code:

```
public void offerApp(Activity activity) {
    Log.d("Launching Market");
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("market://details?id=<PACKAGE>"));
    activity.startActivity(i);
}
```